# How do you debug TCP socket creation in Linux?

Tags: linux, go, sockets, networking, tcp

I am developing a Linux-specific application in Go for a master's project in computer networking. My application quickly adds new IPv6 addresses to the NIC and creates TCP sockets from those addresses. This operation frequently fails, but sometimes works. When it fails, the error messages in Go are vague. I see nothing useful in `dmesg` nor `strace`.

Here is a section of the relevant code:

```
src, err = net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp6", net.JoinHostPort(address.IP.String(), "0"))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// (Some irrelevant lines omitted. I do not think that the tcp6/tcp mismatch is the problem.)

dst, err = net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(ip.String(), strconv.Itoa(port)))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

server_conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", src, dst) // (This is where the problem happens.)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer server_conn.Close()
```

The `error` in Go looks like:

```
dial tcp [2001::xxxx]:0->[2a03:2880:f036:1d:face:b00c:0:3]:443: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Where can I look for more details about **why** `DialTCP` is failing?
I have found discussion of similar `bind` faults on the Internet where other applications are specifying the source address used, but I have not learned of a good debugging approach.

Comment: Does `ip addr` (typically installed using the `iproute2` package) shows that `[2001::xxxx]` as the address really available on one of the host's interfaces? The error basically means the system cannot bind the local socket. The usual case is that your system does not "own" the IP address listed, and it hence naturally cannot use it to send or receive IP packets.

Comment: It should, but that's a good idea -- I'll write a verification function to check if the `src` address is *actually* available on any link.

Comment: [1/2] There is another possible case: the exhaustion of the so-called ephemeral ports: when you ask the system to bind to port 0, it's supposed to pick a free one out of the configured pool (use `/sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`; yes, IPv6 uses that, too). When a TCP connection is shut down, the stack keeps its local port around for some time to wait for duplicated and out-of-order packets possibly delayed in transit. When you make lots of short-lived connections at a hight rate, it's not uncommon to scoop up the whole range and get into the situation there's no free port to assign.

Comment: [2/2] To check for that, use `ss state time-wait` or similar tools. See [this](https://serverfault.com/q/23385) for more info.

Comment: strace output should contain `errno` value if `bind()` fails. Run `strace -e bind ...`. Actually *cannot assign requested address* is straightforward message for *EADDRNOTAVAIL: A nonexistent interface was requested or the requested address was not local.* For lack of ephemeral ports errno should be `EADDRINUSE`.

Comment: @dimich, thanks for the correction.

Comment: 'Cannot assign requested address' when binding means that the specified IP address is not a local address of any NIC in the localhost. IOW your address addition has not yet taken effect. There is no magic solution to debugging, you just have to know what the various `errno` values and error texts mean in practice.

Comment: [1/2] BTW there's no need to `strace` to get errno out of a syscall error in Go: what functions from `net` return when it's a syscall which failed, are errors of type `*os.SyscallError`. These, in turn, have the `Err error` field which is of type `syscall.Errno`, which is an `uintptr`. So you could do something like `var errno syscall.Errno; if errors.As(err, &errno) { fmt.Printf("%[1]s, %[1]d\n", errno)`. The `errno.As` will call `Unwrap` on the error chain until it gets to the errno.

Comment: [2/2] The mnemonic for the errno can be looked up using the `errno` utility (which is packaged as a part of `moreutils` for Debian and its derivatives, FWIW).

Comment: @kostix Since glibc 2.32 there is `strerrorname_np()` function which returns human-readable name for errno value. Unforunatelly i'm not familiar with Go and don't know how to get it from Go, but for a developer it's a golden middle between numberic value and user-oriented error text message.

Comment: «My application quickly adds new IPv6 addresses to the NIC and creates TCP sockets from those addresses. This operation frequently fails, but sometimes works.»–by the way, can you share what method do you use to assigning addresses?

Comment: @kostix I am using https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink API calls to create IP addresses. It works pretty well.

Comment: I think @user207421 was right -- the address was added to the NIC yet somehow not actually usable yet. I never did find a synchronous solution. What I did was queue up a large batch of pre-allocated addresses that would be ready for use when I needed them. Not what I wanted, but it runs with fewer errors now.

Comment: Looks like you might use the same netlink package to _listen_ for address changes on the interface of interest–basically [this](https://manpages.debian.org/7/rtnetlink) (I mean, `NETLINK_ROUTE` updates carried by messages `RTM_NEWADDR`, `RTM_DELADDR`). Your updates then become two-phase: you first tell the kernel to assign an address to an interface and then wait for a message telling the address was actually assigned.